# Open Source syslog-ng RPM for SLES

Tags: syslog-ng

Can anyone point me to an Open source syslog-ng RPM package for SLES 11 (x86, 64-bit)?

Comment: Did you try your install media?

Answer (score 1):

openSUSE 11.3 repository:

[x86_64](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.3/repo/oss/suse/x86_64/syslog-ng-3.1.1-3.7.x86_64.rpm)

[i586](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.3/repo/oss/suse/i586/syslog-ng-3.1.1-3.7.i586.rpm)